# How request rates are calculated for http app server?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

So upon checking history dashboard it seems for a particular http server, for request rate, I see several straight lines for instance

```
abc-dashboard-http 21.27 request/sec
xyz 14.68 request/sec
```

Are they representing correctly? I wonder how request rates are calucalted and stored in meters. 
For `abc-dashboard` I'm aware that a request is made every minute and there are `30 nodes in a cluster`. Going by this scenario, there will be either `1/60 requests/sec or (1*30)/60 request/sec` but what we see as raw in the dashboard doesn't make sense to me. How ? To help understand this better I'm pasting a screenshot of the status - 
[image]

These request rates are added for calculating request/sec. But I'm not aware of the logic and why even when there is no request for many seconds in a particular host, it still have around 0.8 request/sec.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to not conflate the various 'view' into metrics -- you discuss the 'history dashboard' but show a screenshot of the admin console server status, and ask about 'stored in meters' which is yet a third 'view' - unmentioned but important are the Meters History  GUI as well as the Meters Database -- all of which do different types of normalization and aggregation.
The request metrics originate from the same counters internally -- these count the # of requests / time and decay with an exponential decay algorithm.  If you quiesce the system they will *eventually* reach 0 but it takes a while.  Think of rate valued metrics as a slow moving average (per app servers).   What is shown in the server status page is a snapshot of this the same as you would get with xdmp:server-status and xdmp:host-status.  What is shown in the 'Dashboard' is a semi-real time sampled view of these values.  The Meters History GUI shows an aggregate view of the data stored in Meters Database.  The data stored in the Meters Database is a collection of raw (1 minute snapshots),  Hourly  daily and monthly averages (aggregate by time only, unlike the GUI which aggregates across servers -- the raw data only does 'roll ups' over time, it does not combine metrics across servers or types)

Comment: I checked the manual. It says App server rate is no. of queries per sec and not no. of requests per sec. So I want to know what does no. of queries mean?